# jquery mobile dialog doesn't open on first page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, dialog

I've got a problem with using the multi-page dialog as per the documention. I get a problem when, upon the initial visit to a page which has a dialog (multi-page), clicking the button which opens the dialog, it doesn't work. However, if I then refresh the page, it and click the button again, the dialog shows up fine. This occurs on ALL devices.

Any ideas where to start? I have checked code validation and the only thing lacking is some alt tags on some images.

Here is a link:

http://bit.ly/wTnpgi

Click on Galleries then 'Browse Galleries'

**UPDATE 1**

I have found an interesting result. If i access the page from another page through a link (ie: go to gallery from homepage), the dialog doesn't work. BUT, if I go directly to the url via the web browser address bar, it does work. So, its something related to a referral and possibly ajax page loads.

Comment: Could you post a link or some code you have tried? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: i have added a link. I've also gone as far as stripping down the code all the way to just the button and an empty dialog and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out. I read further and further into the docs and stumbled across this paragraph on http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/docs-pages.html:

> It's important to note if you are linking from a mobile page that was
>   loaded via Ajax to a page that contains multiple internal pages, you
>   need to add a rel="external" or data-ajax="false" to the link. This
>   tells the framework to do a full page reload to clear out the Ajax
>   hash in the URL. This is critical because Ajax pages use the hash (#)
>   to track the Ajax history, while multiple internal pages use the hash
>   to indicate internal pages so there will be conflicts in the hash
>   between these two modes.
>
> For example, a link to a page containing multiple internal pages would
>   look like this: Multi-page
>   link

When i add the rel to the referral link, it works. Fun times.

Comment: Just a FYI those are the release notes for the Alpha version, jQM has an official 1.0 version release http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/

Comment: For redirections coming through forms, `rel="external"` is not possible. But you can use `target="_self"`, and it will work everywhere (as shown by [this answer on "rel=external for forms"](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/rel-external-for-forms#14737000002597231))

Comment: I found target="_self" to be the most reliable and universally applicable.